# OS X IPC get process-ID in C

Tags: c++, c, macos, ipc, pid

Is there any server-client like inter-process-communication method which allows:

- the server to reliably get the process-ID of a connected client
- any client-application to connect to the server
- works in C/C++
- Optionally: Works also on Linux

Comment: I don't believe so; can't you get the client to tell you via the network connection as part of the handshake?

Comment: The problem is that the client could say anything. I want to be able to know which process connects to the server. File-permissions do not work because sadly most processes run as the same user...

Comment: You could try a two way connection: First you transfer a port right to a task in the client to the server (in which case the client would have to send a port right to its own task port), and the server then inserts the actual send right into that task. That way you know to some extend which process owns the port right.

Comment: @JustSid Are you talking about TCP/IP ports or about Mach-ports? (I assume Mach-ports). If so, how do I know into which task I insert the send-right? Have you some documentation or examples for me?

Comment: @K.Biermann Mach IPC. You know which task to insert the port right because the client gave you a send right to it. You would use [mach_port_insert_right](http://web.mit.edu/darwin/src/modules/xnu/osfmk/man/mach_port_insert_right.html)

Comment: The idea is you call [mach_task_self](http://web.mit.edu/darwin/src/modules/xnu/osfmk/man/mach_task_self.html) to get your task port, and then send a send right to the server which then uses [mach_port_insert_right](http://web.mit.edu/darwin/src/modules/xnu/osfmk/man/mach_port_insert_right.html) to insert a send right associated with that task into the task.

Comment: Wow... If you then can tell me how to obtain the PID from this (use task_info on the result of mach_task_self?) and put it in an answer, I'll accept it. This is what I was looking for 

Comment: @K.Biermann That is a bit more complicated, because you can have mach tasks without BSD process and no pid (so there is no direct API as far as I know). Is your server running as root by any chance, or can you make it run as root? In that case you could use `task_for_pid()` to do the reverse, ie get a task right for a pid.

Comment: Alternatively you can use the `Security.framework` and code signing to obtain rights for `task_for_pid`. That's not root and doesn't elevate your programs rights to root, but it'll still ask for a password (just from within the app and it might be nicer). Oh and it can't be a command line tool, but has to be a `.app` bundle.

Comment: Yup, my server will run as root; task_for_pid() is a good idea:
The client sends it's PID to my server, my server obtains a mach_port_name_t of the process which has the PID and allows it with mach_port_insert_right to talk to me. If I got the real PID the application can talk to me; if I got an faked PID it won't hurt. 
You've helped me a lot. Post this as an answer and I'll accept it. 

Comment: @K.Biermann Cheers! Sorry for the delay, real life got in the way. I just poste it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your server runs with root rights, you can work with `task_for_pid()` and a two way connection. First, the client will send its pid to the server via some special bootstrap port on the server, the server will then resolve the pid via `task_for_pid` to a task port and then use `mach_port_insert_right` to insert a send right to a new port into the client. The new port is then exclusively to the client and you know what security level the client has.